# wildfly-maven-plugin doesn't deploy anything

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, wildfly-8

I would like Maven to start up a wildfly server which is available in my target-folder at /path/to/project/target/wildfly-8.1.2-Final. The plugin is supposed to deploy a war-artifact during pre-integration-test phase. That very artifact was created by maven-war-plugin during package-phase right before wildfly-maven-plugin starts.

When running the maven build, wildfly starts up, however does not deploy anything. It just hangs after starting up and lets the Maven build fail after a timeout of 60 seconds...

This is my effective pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Alpha8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>start</goal>
          <goal>deploy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <port>18080</port>
          <timeout>60</timeout>
          <skip>false</skip>
          <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
          <name>/path/to/project/target/my-artifact.war</name>
          <targetDir>/path/to/project/target/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments</targetDir>
          <server-config>standalone.xml</server-config>
          <username>wildfly-test</username>
          <password>wildfly.1234</password>
          <add-user>
            <users>
              <user>
                <username>wildfly-admin</username>
                <password>wildfly.1234</password>
                <groups>
                  <group>admin</group>
                  <group>user</group>
                </groups>
                <application-user>false</application-user>
                <realm>ManagementRealm</realm>
              </user>
              <user>
                <username>wildfly-test</username>
                <password>wildfly.1234</password>
                <groups>
                  <group>user</group>
                </groups>
                <application-user>true</application-user>
                <realm>ApplicationRealm</realm>
              </user>
            </users>
          </add-user>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>undeploy</goal>
          <goal>shutdown</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
          <port>18888</port>
          <skip>false</skip>
          <name>/path/to/project/target/my-artifact.war</name>
          <targetDir>/path/to/project/target/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments</targetDir>
          <server-config>standalone.xml</server-config>
          <username>wildfly-test</username>
          <password>wildfly.1234</password>
          <add-user>
            <users>
              <user>
                <username>wildfly-admin</username>
                <password>wildfly.1234</password>
                <groups>
                  <group>admin</group>
                  <group>user</group>
                </groups>
                <application-user>false</application-user>
                <realm>ManagementRealm</realm>
              </user>
              <user>
                <username>wildfly-test</username>
                <password>wildfly.1234</password>
                <groups>
                  <group>user</group>
                </groups>
                <application-user>true</application-user>
                <realm>ApplicationRealm</realm>
              </user>
            </users>
          </add-user>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <skip>false</skip>
      <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
      <port>18080</port>
      <name>/path/to/project/target/my-artifact.war</name>
      <targetDir>/path/to/project/target/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments</targetDir>
      <server-config>standalone.xml</server-config>
      <username>wildfly-test</username>
      <password>wildfly.1234</password>
      <add-user>
        <users>
          <user>
            <username>wildfly-admin</username>
            <password>wildfly.1234</password>
            <groups>
              <group>admin</group>
              <group>user</group>
            </groups>
            <application-user>false</application-user>
            <realm>ManagementRealm</realm>
          </user>
          <user>
            <username>wildfly-test</username>
            <password>wildfly.1234</password>
            <groups>
              <group>user</group>
            </groups>
            <application-user>true</application-user>
            <realm>ApplicationRealm</realm>
          </user>
        </users>
      </add-user>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Has anybody experienced a similar behaviour?

Maybe somebody could give me a pointer on what is wrong here... Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Walter

Comment: As Maurice spotted correctly, the line <port>18888</port> is incorrect! It should be <port>18080</port>

Comment: However, if I use port 9990 (and therefore do not change the default port), the deployment works perfectly fine. I believe this to be a bug in wildfly-maven-plugin. It should be possible to change the default port, right? Would be great if somebody could confirm this...

Answer (score 0):

You are using port 18080. I guess, as you are using 18888 either you changed the port?
The default configuration is 8080.

Comment: Um... yes and no.

First, you are right that there is a typo. Of course, it should be 18080 for both executions... Thanks. I completely missed that.

The default, however, is not 8080, but 9990! See https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/run-mojo.html#port

That hint was actually crucial, because if I use 9990 (and therefore do not change the default port), the deployment works perfectly fine.

I believe this to be a bug in wildfly-maven-plugin. It should be possible to change the default port, right? Would be great if somebody could confirm this...

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation I can tell it's not clear what `<port/>` is used for. The `port` configuration property is used to tell the plugin which port the management interface is listening on. That is why using port `9990` works. Same with the `<hostname/>`.

The `<targetDir/>` seems to be wrong as well. It's poorly named, but that directory is used find the deployment. Essentially it's the target directory where maven put the compiled archive.

Looking at the configuration you're defining a lot of the defaults that shouldn't be necessary. Below is an example stripped down version of the plugin configuration from the example you posted.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0.Alpha8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>start</goal>
        <goal>deploy</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <add-user>
          <users>
            <user>
              <username>wildfly-admin</username>
              <password>wildfly.1234</password>
              <groups>
                <group>admin</group>
                <group>user</group>
              </groups>
              <application-user>false</application-user>
              <realm>ManagementRealm</realm>
            </user>
            <user>
              <username>wildfly-test</username>
              <password>wildfly.1234</password>
              <groups>
                <group>user</group>
              </groups>
              <application-user>true</application-user>
              <realm>ApplicationRealm</realm>
            </user>
          </users>
        </add-user>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>undeploy</goal>
        <goal>shutdown</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```