# Change http port in wildfly maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, maven-plugin, wildfly-10

I would like to change the default HTTP port using the **wildfly-maven-plugin** to 8380. Usually, I can do that changing the offset, but [this is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44518730/2387977), my changes are ignored and HTTP port continues on 8080.

I'm starting wildfly in the same maven project, because this is way more practical (download and start automatically). Just like that:

```
mvn wildfly:run -Dwildfly.version=10.1.0.Final
```

My project contains JAR, WAR and EAR. Classic structure.

As I understood from another SO questions, I need to put the plugin entry in each pom.xml that needs to be ignored, putting `<skip>true</skip>` in pom.xml of the: root, WAR and JAR. Just like that:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If I not skip this guys, the Wildfly try to deploy the JAR/WAR/Root, what is not my objective. I would like to deploy only the EAR.

To do that, I use the `<skip>false</skip>`  only for pom.xml of the EAR:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>false</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The `localhost:8080/app/` works well after that.

But if I try to change the offset or http port, nothing different happens. This is some of the args that I already try on `<configuration/>` without success:

```
<server-args>
    <server-arg>-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=300</server-arg>
</server-args>

<jvmArgs>-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=300</jvmArgs>

<jvmArgs>-Djboss.http.port=8380</jvmArgs>
```

The change that have some effect was:

```
<serverConfig>standalone.xml</serverConfig>
<server-args>
    <server-arg>-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=300</server-arg>
</server-args>
<filename>${project.build.finalName}.ear</filename>
```

This also have changed the port (`jvmArgs` is [deprecated](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/start-mojo.html#jvmArgs)):

```
<javaOpts>-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=300</javaOpts>
```

But in both cases the EAR application is not deployed...

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

The [jvmArgs is deprecated](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/start-mojo.html#jvmArgs). I used javaOpts:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>false</skip>
        <javaOpts>-Djboss.http.port=8380</javaOpts>
        <filename>${project.build.finalName}.ear</filename>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Works!

You can use too:

```
<javaOpts>
    <javaOpt>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=9087,server=y,suspend=n</javaOpt>
    <javaOpt>-Djboss.http.port=8380</javaOpt>
</javaOpts>
```

To use more than one option for the JVM. In this example above I'm showing how to include a parameter to debug the Wildfly using the maven plugin.

But it's still a mistery why the EAR is not deployed when I use the offset configuration.

Answer (score -3):

try not skipping the configuration :D

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <port>8380</port>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi! The skip tag is `false`. This `port` is for the Wildfly Management Console (very confuse, I know), the default is 9990. I updated my question with another try that partially works...